# How to check if a tree is a binary search tree?

Tags: python

I built an algorithm that checks if the tree is a binary search tree, but it always returns true to me and I can not find the problem
(t2) should return false

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, entry, left=None, right=None):
        self.entry = entry
        self.left = left
        self.right = right    
    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.left and not self.right:
            return "Tree({0})".format(repr(self.entry))
        return "Tree({0},{1},{2})".format(repr(self.entry), repr(self.left), repr(self.right))

def build_tree(tree):
  if tree:
    (entry, left, right) = (tree + (None, None))[:3]
    return Tree(entry, build_tree(left), build_tree(right))
  else:
    return None

def is_BST_tree(node):
    if node == None or (node.left == None and node.right == None):
        return True

    elif node.right == None:
        return node.left.data < node.data and is_BST_tree(node.left)

    elif node.left == None:
        return node.right.data >= node.data and is_BST_tree(node.right)

    return is_BST_tree(node.left) and is_BST_tree(node.right)

tree1 = (12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (14,), (18,)))
tree2 = (12, (6, (2,), (8,)), (15, (7,), (20,)))
print(is_BST_tree(t1))
print(is_BST_tree(t2))
```

t2 should be return false

Comment: I corrected my answer as my first attempt was indeed wrong.

Comment: Please consider accepting and/or upvoting answers when they are correct.